# Why do templated class data members require the static keyword?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, static

What is the rationale that this does not compile?

```
class Math{
   template<typename T>
   std::map<int, T> m;   // error: member 'm' declared as a template
};
```

while making the data member `static` compiles?

```
class Math{
   template<typename T>
   static std::map<int, T> m;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was posted by [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4706785/peter) (under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license), as a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65210556/why-do-templated-class-members-variables-require-the-static-keyword#comment115285767_65210556) to the question [Why do templated class data members require the static keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65210556/why-do-templated-class-members-variables-require-the-static-keyword).

---

> For exactly the reason the diagnostic described. A non-static data member of a class cannot be a template, since it means that each instance of the class has an unbounded (potentially infinite) number of members named `m` - which would all need to be stored in an instance of the class simultaneously. That makes the size of the containing class indeterminate. A static member can be a template, since each instantiation can be referred to unambiguously and need not all be stored simultaneously in a single object. It's not a case of `static` being needed - one case is achievable and one is not